# Creating an instance from MyClass.class with multiple parameters

Tags: java, object, constructor, instantiation

I want to create an instance of Item.class. It takes two objects as constructor parameters.

```
First FirstObject = new First();
Second SecondObject = new Second();

 Class[] constructorArgs = new Class[]{First.class,Second.class};

 Item.class.getConstructor(constructorArgs).newInstance(FirstObject, SecondObject);
```

this doesn't seem to work. I get a compiler error that says:

```
unhandled exception Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodException
```

How to fix?

Comment: Please! Don't name variables starting with a capital letter. Do `firstObject` instead of `FirstObject`. It makes it look like a class.

Comment: Just names for example purposes, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoSuchMethodException`is a checked exception so you either need to wrap your `getConstructor()` call in a `try-catch` block or declare that the method where this code is `throws` this exception.

```
try {
    Item.class.getConstructor(constructorArgs).newInstance(FirstObject, SecondObject);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  // log the error
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```